# Probability in simultaneous parallel radioactive decay

Tags: nuclear-physics, probability, radioactivity

Probability of survival (PoS) and probability of decay(PoD) in simple radioactive decay (X --> Y : $\lambda$ as disintegration constant) are given by:
PoS = $e^{-\lambda t}$ and PoD = $ 1- e^{-\lambda t}$

Then I had a doubt that can we find similar probabilities of decay for different paths of radioactivity in simultaneous parallel radioactive decay?
For eg:
A --> B (λ <sub>1</sub> : disintegration constant 1)
A --> C (λ <sub>2</sub> : disintegration constant 2)

I calculated that probability of path 1 (A to B) should be $\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2} (1-e^ {-(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)t}) $  and that of path 2 (A to C) should be $\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2} (1-e^ {-(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)t}) $.

Am I right in thinking this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's correct. You can find more detail on [Alternative modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioactive_decay) of radioactive decay.